# Jackson: deserialize any json

Tags: java, json, jackson

This shouldn't be too difficult ... but I seem to be blind and don't find the answer myself.

Using Jackson I'd like to deserialize *any* ** JSON in a Java Map.
The `Array` part is making the trouble.

*any* json could look like:
`{ "foo": "bar" }` or `{ "test": [ { "a": 123, "b": "erny" }, { "a": ... and so on`

these should deserialize in (pseudocode):

```
Map( foo => "bar" )
Map( test => Array( 
    Map( a => 123, b=>erny ),
    Map( a => ... and so on
) )
```

I don't care much for the types of Arrays and Maps as long as they are that nor for the types of values. (But would be nice if integers were represented as such).

If I try `om.readValue( json, Map.class )` I get  *Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY* error if the json contains an array.

I'm using Jackson quite successfully for all my complicated JSON stuff but how to do the simple one?

**NOTE: Jackson does exactly what I want it to do using the syntax above. The problem was a bug in my json. So this question doesn't make sense.**

**) *any* is not completely true. Every JSON I use is a map on its lowest level.

Comment: delete because the problem wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson can deserialize JSON objects into `java.util.Map` and JSON arrays into `java.util.List`

From your error message it seems you are trying to deserialize a JSON array into a java.util.Map which is not possible.

Comment: You're right of cause. The problem is (as in most of the cases) Layer 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonAnyGetter public Map<String, Object> getOtherInfo() { return otherInfo; }
```